# Can't source bash dotfiles when running commands using the subprocess module in python

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I am trying to write a python script that runs a command through bash.

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

The script is working fine except that it does not source my bash aliases or other configs. How do I include them ? Is there a better way of doing this in python ?

Comment: You should take a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work) for information about how to enable aliases for non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 1):

Execute bash with the `--init-file` argument. From the bash manpage:

> ```
>    --init-file file
>    --rcfile file
>           Execute  commands  from file instead of the system wide initial‐
>           ization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the standard personal initial‐
>           ization  file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see INVOCA‐
>           TION below).
> ```

Comment: How do I pass arguments to the shell executable ?
Using `executable='/bin/bash --init-file /home/user/.bash_aliases'` gives `No such file or directory`

Comment: you pass in a list of arguments `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])` it's described in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: otherwise the whole string in your `executable` is interpreted as the application to find and execute and of course there's no such application