# How to create alias for bash inside php exec?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, exec

I have code like this:

```
public function shell($code) {
    $code = preg_replace('/"/', '\\"', $code);
    exec('bash -c "' . $code . '"', $result);
    return $result;
}
```

and I want to add `alias ls="ls --color=always"`. I've try to put it in .bashrc file that I've created just for that shell in my project directory and use:

```
exec('bash -c ". .bashrc;' . $code . '"', $result);
```

but this don't work, I'm in correct directory because I see that file when I call `ls -A`.

I've also try `--init-file` and `--rcfile` with just a file and full path.

How can I add aliases and functions to that shell? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using functions is probably a better choice anyway. However, note that **it is possible to use aliases** [if you set the `expand_aliases` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615973/27581):

```
<?php
$code = 'ls';
$aliases = '
    shopt -s expand_aliases
    alias ls="ls -l"';
$code = $aliases . "\n" . $code;
exec('bash -c ' . escapeshellarg($code), $result);
echo implode("\n", $result) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ php aliasexec.php 
total 12
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mlk mlk 198 Feb 18 11:18 aliasexec.php
```

---

This is what [the man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) has to say (emphasis mine):

> Aliases  are  not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless
>   the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt […].
>
> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
>   confusing.  Bash always reads at  least one  complete line of input
>   before executing any of the commands on that line.  Aliases are
>   expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed.  **Therefore,
>   an alias definition appearing on  the  same  line  as another  command
>   does  not  take  effect until the next line of input is read. […] To
>   be safe, always put alias definitions on a separate line**, and do not
>   use alias in compound commands.
>
> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

That is why you must use newlines and not the `;` character to define the alias.

Comment: Better solution then my, because it actually solve the issue. I've try the same thing but I put `shopt` into a file and I use semicolons instead of newlines.

Comment: @jcubic yeah, the way `alias` works is weird and that's why functions are better. I added an explanation of why you have to use newline and not semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that work is to add functions instead of aliases:

```
function ls() {
    /bin/ls --color=always $@;
}
function grep() {
    /bin/grep --color=always $@;
}
```

Comment: Check out [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) sometime. It's good for spotting bugs in sh/bash code.