# How can I call an alias name in a shell script by concatenating two string?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have an alias that looks like the following

```
alias testalias12569537329="echo it works"
```

My question is: How can I call `testalias12569537329` in a shell script by concatenating two strings?

```
x="testalias"
x+="12569537329" #timestamp
exec $x #command not found
```

I know that I can directly call testalias12569537329 in the shell script. But I would like to manipulate the timestamp. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `$(x)`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But $(x) did not work for me. I'm using zsh tho.

Comment: Instead of working around the limitations of aliases, I would suggest using a function which does something depending on a parameter.You could then just call it `testfunc $timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$ eval $x
```

Comment: Calling an alias from a non-interactive shell requires [`shopt -s expand_aliases`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work). Otherwise, the script will report: `testalias12569537329: command not found`