# How to use Bash aliases from a shell in a Ruby script on OS X?

Tags: ruby, bash, alias

How can I execute aliases from my Bash shell in a Ruby script?

Here's the code:

```
aliases = [ 'ul', 'ur', 'dl', 'dr', 'll', 'rr', 'up', 'down', 'big', 'cen' ]

while true
    a = aliases.sample
    `#{a}`
    puts `figlet -f doh "#{a}"`
end
```

I would like to:

- select a random shell alias from the `aliases` array. (These aliases are aliases that I can use in my shell as defined in my `.bashrc`),
- execute the selected alias,
- print the name of the selected alias to the terminal screen using `figlet`.

However:

- When I execute `./mysciprt` I get:

  > ```
  > ul: command not found
  > ```

Comment: Update: I was wrong to say that you cannot invoke alias from ruby code. See my question for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705936/how-do-you-invoke-alias-from-ruby-code-for-zsh-shell/33718936#33718936

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick check of the Bash man page showed:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt` (see the description of `shopt` under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

A quick search for "shell shopt expand_aliases" showed a bunch of hits.

See "[Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/a/183980)", "[Why aliases in a non-interactive Bash shell do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work)", "[Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases)" and "[Non-interactive shell expand alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158038/non-interactive-shell-expand-alias)".

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the solution is to run the shell commands inside the Ruby script as an interactive shell (so that `.bashrc` is sourced and aliases are available to shell's environment):

```
aliases = [ 'ul', 'ur', 'dl', 'dr', 'll', 'rr', 'up', 'down', 'big', 'cen' ]

while true
    a = aliases.sample
    `bash -ic '#{a}'`
    puts `figlet -f doh "#{a}"` 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`alias` is a keyword and should never be used as a variable name or a method name.

Answer (score 0):

1. The word `alias` is a keyword in Ruby, so you can't use it as an identifier.
2. When you do a `source xxxx` from Bash, it interprets the file "xxxx" as a Bash program. Your file is a Ruby program, so it can't be sourced.