# How do you invoke alias from ruby code for zsh shell?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh

I would like to invoke alias from ruby code so as to test the alias which I programmatically inserted into the dotfile. Say for example, the alias is the following:

```
alias something="echo somethingelse"
```

I searched the web and found the solution for bash:

```
  #solution for bash
   system %(
     source ~/.bash_profile
     shopt -s expand_aliases
     something
   )
```

However, this does not work for zsh.

I tried to invoke the alias using the following code (and a combination of other commands) but to no avail.

```
  system %(
    exec zsh #this seems to source .zshrc 
    something #this does not work
  )
```

I would like it to work for zsh too. How can I get it working for zsh? Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks in advance!

I have also tested the following but they don't work:

```
  system %(
     # exec /bin/zsh #this causes the subsequent lines to not run. 
     source ~/.zshrc #this causes the error lines to be printed
     # setopt aliases #don't think it helps
     something #trying to invoke this which is already in zshrc   
  )
```

The error messages:

- /Users/ytbryan/.zprezto/init.zsh: line 14: autoload: command not
  found
- /Users/ytbryan/.zprezto/init.zsh: line 15: print: command not
  found
- /Users/ytbryan/.zshrc: line 42: `@': not a valid identifier

Comment: `shopt` is a bash builtin, not a zsh builtin. In zsh we use `setopt`. Try `setopt aliases` in place of `shopt -s expand_aliases`. (And of course you need to source the appropriate runcom for zsh.)

Comment: Re `exec zsh #this seems to source .zshrc`: I doubt that. `.zshrc` is only sourced for interactive shells. I'm not very familiar with Ruby, but I really doubt a `system` call will start an interactive shell. Just manually source `.zshrc`.

Comment: I just tried and `exec zsh` in Ruby system call doesn't work like you want it to. It executes `exec zsh` in your current shell. In light of that, I think you probably should run `zsh -c` instead. Note that aliases may not work when run from `zsh -c`, but you can force an expansion by accessing the associative array `aliases` (and perform word splitting). E.g., try the following command in your `system` call: `zsh -c 'alias foo="echo bar"; ${=aliases[foo]}'` (result is `bar`). Another example that takes arguments: `zsh -c 'alias foo=echo; ${=aliases[foo]} $@' -- 1 2 3` (result is `1 2 3`).

Comment: Wow. Thanks @4ae1e1. Appreciate the effort. 

Yes, `exec zsh` does not work on system(). I am unsure why. 

Unfortunately, I am unable to use `zsh -c 'alias foo="echo bar"; ${=aliases[foo]}'` as the objective is to invoke (so as to test) a permanent alias which was programmatically inserted into the dotfile. Not to call an alias that is inserted at real-time from ruby. 

I wonder what is the real problem here. I don't think `setopt` helps.

Comment: Just `source` your dotfile. I defined the alias so that you can easily test this approach without any prerequisite, not that it is required. Just replace `alias foo="echo bar"` with `source ~/.zshrc` for instance.

Comment: cool. it works. system %(zsh -c 'source ~/.zshrc; ${=aliases[something]}')

Thank you so much. @4ae1e1

Comment: No problem. I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: Why would you want to, though? Making your scripts depend on your personal configuration files make them impossible for anyone else to use (including yourself in most nontrivial situations).

Comment: @tripleee It's still a work in progress but I am making this -> https://rubygems.org/gems/aka2

I wanted a way to test the inserted (or destroyed or edited) aliases in the dotfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to run Zsh code via `zsh -c`. Aliases are not expanded when run from `zsh -c`, but the builtin `aliases` array is still accessible, so one can still expand aliases by manually retrieving expansions from the array and manually performing word splitting. This should cover most of the commonly seen aliases. For more advanced aliases (that involves process substitution, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, brace expansion, filename expansion or filename generation, or that is more than a simple command), one might need to use `eval` (but one needs to be very cautious when using `eval`, and never ever use it when input comes from an untrusted source, or from a trusted but possibly tempered-with source).

Example code that could be embedded in Ruby `system` calls:

```
> zsh -c 'alias foo="print bar"; ${=aliases[foo]}'
bar
> zsh -c 'alias foo=print; ${=aliases[foo]} $@' -- 1 2 3
1 2 3
> zsh -c 'alias foo="print a b c | grep -o a"; ${=aliases[foo]}'  # simple case where naive expansion fails
a b c | grep -o a
> zsh -c 'alias foo="print a b c | grep -o a"; eval "$aliases[foo]"'  # eval comes to rescue, but be extra careful
a
```

Note that `source` works in `zsh -c`, so the alias definitions above could be sourced from any file just fine.