# ssh remote command source interactive startup scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

So I've found that running `ssh remote "<command>"` runs the remote shell in non-interactive mode, thus it doesn't source the same startup scripts as if it were an interactive shell. My issue is that I need to source these startup scripts when running a remote command, but I don't actually need an interactive shell, just the startup scripts. Is there anyway I can force the non-interactive shell to source the same startup scripts for an interactive shell?

Comment: how would this work? the scripts are on your local machine and you want to source them in the remote shell?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want it to source the scripts on the remote machine, in the remote shell

Answer (score 1):

You could have your `"command"` do the sourcing you want.  For example, it could become `". .bashrc; command"`

Or you could invoke your command with `bash -i "..."` to tell bash to start in interactive mode even if it normally wouldn't have.

Or you could pass in the `BASH_ENV` shell variable that points to the startup script that you want, since `bash` will source that file when started in non-interactive mode.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to tell bash to start in interactive mode? I tried `ssh remote bash -i "bin/some_script.sh"` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that the variables you want are in your `.bashrc` then?  Your example works with a dummy script for me, though it won't do aliases if that's what you're trying to use.  Then you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work

Comment: I suspect it's `-t` you were thinking about rather than `-i`.  `-i` is to specify an identity file.  `-t` is to force a pseudo terminal.

Comment: @MatthewWalker the `-i` there is an argument to `bash` not to `ssh` , it's intended as part of the command being executed remotely here.