# Bash, alias/custom functions not found with ssh connection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have the computer A (kali linux) where I defined some aliases and functions in the bash_aliases for the user 'test'.
I can use these aliases/functions from the computer A without any problem.

With the computer B, I connect to A with SSH command and I try execute aliases/functions I defined. But I get the error "bash: myaliasA: command not found"

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work) I see I must add the "shopt -s expand_aliases" command.

I add this in the .bashrc of the computer A (and source .bashrc), but I still get the same error (command not found)

I add this in the .bashrc of the computer B (and source .bashrc), same, I still get "command not found" when I connect with ssh

I don't understand where is the issue :/

In the computer A, when I run the command "shopt" I get :

```
...
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
...
```

Same in the computer B :

```
...
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
...
```

From my computer A, I can execute all my alias/functions without any problem.

From my computer B, when I execute this command :

```
ssh userA@ipofcomputerA -p xxxx "alias"
```

This command return nothing

But if I execute :

```
ssh userA@ipofcomputerA -p xxxx "shopt"
```

I get :

```
...
execfail        off
expand_aliases  off
extdebug        off
...
```

The expand_aliases is set to **off** !

So, I test this :

```
ssh userA@ipofcomputerA -p xxxx "shopt -s expand_aliases ; shopt ; myaliasA"
```

and

```
ssh userA@ipofcomputerA -p xxxx "shopt -s expand_aliases ; shopt ; source .bashrc ; myaliasA"
```

With this two commands, I get :

```
...
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
...
```

but I get after "bash: myaliasA: command not found"

I'm going crazy x) haha

Comment: I suggest to use an interactive shell: `ssh userA@ipofcomputerA -p xxxx bash -ic "alias"`

Comment: Sometimes `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/default/bash` is not set to load ~/.bash_aliases - do you see any mention of it?

Comment: @Cyrus, it works ! i get the output of my alias, but I get too this 'warning' :  "cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device" and "bash: no job control in this shell". How can I get the output of my alias without these warning ? :)

Comment: @jedifans, in .bashrc , the bash_aliases is loaded

Comment: You will need to check how kali Linux handles sourcing your `~/.bashrc`. `ssh` generally doesn't trigger an interactive shell. Most distros have a scheme in either /etc/profile and/or /etc/bash.bashrc that will trigger the read of your bashrc on ssh login. SuSE does it different than Arch, that does it different than Kali. So check what Kali requires.

Comment: The immediate problem is that the entire command line is parsed before `expand_aliases` is enabled.  You can force this by replacing the semicolons with newlines IIRC.  A better approach altogether is to not require aliases - they are problematic for a number of reasons, including but not limited to this.

Comment: I wish I was able to find a better duplicate where this is properly explained, but the comment above should be enough to settle this for you.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers ! @tripleee : can you explain what is "newlines IIRC" ? I didnt understand :/

Comment: IIRC means ["if I recall correctly"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=iirc).  The newline trick is explained e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work#comment65785947_1615973).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that when you ssh you use the same shell for which the configuration exists, and try to `reset` in order to reload the .bashrc files.

On a side note, a good way to do this is to open a new `tmux` session and attach to it everytime you ssh into your server.

Comment: before use new tools (tmux..), I would like understand why the "native" way doesn't work :) I don't understand your first sentence : "you use the same shell for which the configuration exists", I connect to the userA with ssh to computer A, with the userA from the computer A I can use all alias/functions without any problem. I reload (source..) basrh files in the order I describe in my initial post

Comment: You might be ssh-ing into zsh or something