# ddev exec: command not found (.bash_aliases)

Tags: ddev

In a local ddev instance, I have added a few aliases and functions to `.ddev/homeadditions/bash_aliases`.

For example: `alias ll="ls -lhA"`

While `ddev ssh` and then `ll` will work, `ddev exec ll` returns

```
bash: ll: command not found
Failed to execute command ll: exit status 127
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really about how bash works, not about how ddev works. The .bashrc (and thus .bash_aliases, which gets loaded by .bashrc) is only loaded by *interactive* shells (contexts like `ddev ssh`). Here'a an Stack Overflow answer on it: [Why aliases in a non-interactive Bash shell do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615877/why-aliases-in-a-non-interactive-bash-shell-do-not-work)

`ddev exec` just does a `bash -c "<your command>"`, and `bash -c` is noninteractive by design.

You might consider adding ddev custom web commands for things you can't live without.

A `ddev ll` custom command could work like this. Create a file named "ll" in .ddev/commands/web with the contents

```
#!/bin/bash

## Description: Run ls -l inside web container
## Usage: ll [flags] [arguments]
## Example: "ddev ll"  or `ddev ll /tmp`

ls -l $@
```

Comment: Incredible!! It works! And it also looks a lot more serious. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've posted my use case below

Comment: PS: to reload ./ddev/docker-compose.env.yaml, I have to `ddev restart`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of my setup (actually, I have scripts more than just `ll`)

.ddev/docker-compose.env.yaml

```
version: '3.6'


services:
  web:
    environment:
    - PROD_USER=foo
    - PROD_SERVER=bar.com
    - PROD_ROOT=path/to/root
    - LOCAL_ROOT=that/path/to/root
    - ASSET_DIRS=bi ba bu
```

.ddev/commands/web/sync_down_files

```
#!/bin/bash

# rsync prod assets to local

# download all assets
for directory in ${ASSET_DIRS} ; do
    rsync -zra \
        --delete \
        --exclude='.env' \
        ${PROD_USER}@${PROD_SERVER}:/home/${PROD_USER}/${PROD_ROOT}/$directory \
        ${LOCAL_ROOT};
done
```

Now I do `ddev sync_down_files` and get all remote assets into the local site. Same for the db.